# Angular2 - how to destructure a Rails json error response into a string

Tags: json, angular, dictionary, rails-api

An error response from a Rails API gives me this json body:

{"mobile":["is already taken"],"email":["is already taken"]}

As you can see, each field can have an array of error messages associated with it.

I am trying to 'deconstruct' this into a simple string:

"mobile is already taken, email is already taken"

I was trying to use map and provide it with a function. Obviously I need to account for the fact that there could be several elements in these arrays, eg:

{"mobile":["is already taken","must start 07 for UK"],"email":["is already taken"]}

which should then become:

"mobile is already taken, mobile must start 07 for UK, email is already taken"

Comment: do you have any example of code what you already tried?

Comment: The code I tried was so terrible I threw it away. I'm new to using map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be done like this:

```
let a = JSON.parse('{"mobile":["is already taken","must start 07 for UK"],"email":["is already taken"]}');
let message = Object.keys(a).reduce((prev, next) => prev.concat(a[next].map(v => next + ' ' + v).join(', ')), []).join(', ');
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. Although I'm trying to learn FP, this (as a noob) seems quite complex compared to the answer from PierreDuc. It seems to me that maintaining his solution is far easier ... kind of puts me off the FP way of doing things when code is so unreadable...but maybe that is just lack of exp.

Comment: 90% of this code are standard `Array` methods and new fat arrow functions allow less verbose syntax.

Comment: I guess I just have to practice more with map and reduce...a LOT more, lol.

Answer (score 1):

Without any actual effort on your hand, or at least, no code provided, it feels like doing someone's homework. On the other hand, these are the fun things I like. No need for maps or whatever. Just plain TypeScript:

```
let errorMessages: string[] = [];

let json: string = {"mobile":["is already taken","must start 07 for UK"],"email":["is already taken"]};

let keys: string[] = Object.keys(json);

for(let key of keys) {
   for(let msg of json[key]) {
       errorMessages.push(key + ' ' + msg);
   }
}

console.log(errorMessages.join(', '));
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying to get the hang of functional programming and avoiding using loops. At least you got further than I did even with using a for loop. :)

Comment: This is actually quite clever, thank you, I learned a lot from trying out your solution.

Comment: Verbosity versus one liners. Where to draw the line. I personally like simple code over chained coding. Like you mentioned above, it makes it easier to read, debug and maintain. Obviously with such a small example as this, there is no big difference. Guess it comes down to what your codestyle is. Even though I'm very familiar with reduce/map, it took me a while to figure out what was going on up here :)